# Suspend and edit previous single line commands

Tags: shell, command-line, process, kill

Say I want to modify the latter of some concatenated command line options, is it possible without killing the first command?

Specifically I have compile and run scripts executed thusly:

```
> compile ; run
```

The compile is in progress (half way through two hour duration), but new information tells me I don't really want the "run" command to run anymore (it launches a lot of background processes I don't want to go clean up).

Is there a way to accomplish this adjustment or should I just be smarter about how I string together commands in the future?

Comment: You should probably be "smarter" and use `&&` instead of `;`.

Comment: To clarify, I only know that I want to cancel the run after the compile has been running a while (and I don't want to restart the compile) and I want the run to be cancelled regardless of exit code from the compile.

Comment: That's the idea, when linked with `&&` the `run` will not run if the `compile` is stopped.

Comment: I want the `compile` to finish for sure, and regardless of `compile`'s exit code I want `run` **not** to run. I only came to find this out after an email came in an hour after my command was launched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
compile && { test -f /path/to/dont_run || run; }
```

should solve your problem. `touch /path/to/dont_run` would prevent `run` from being executed. You can make this more complicated (and more convenient) by e.g. defining a shell function cond_run_cmd which does some check like that, limited to its tty (so that you can have several in parallel) or whatever.